# is it ok to use jquery inside ember controller or component

Tags: ember.js

I wanted to follow ember js rules thoroughly.but I am novice to ember js so I am struggle to find ember standard way of doing coding.

Is it ok to do some jquery code inside ember component or controller ?

is it not good to use jquery inside there ?I think it not good to use jquery there.

Comment: I'm no expert, but if you are managing the DOM, I think using jquery is fine. You can use Ember.$.

Comment: I am in my beginning pace of the project I wonder whether if I use jquery heavy on component and controller ultimately end up with out of the way of doing it in ember.

Comment: I think you should use ember where you can. It's okay to comeback and refactor your use of jquery to a ember implementation as you learn more/get more experience using ember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to minimise the usage of the jQuery in your Ember application unless that is a 3-rd party addon/library.

The reason to do so is that if you introduce jQuery to the application. You have to manually manage your application's state (sync all the state between different components for example).

Doing so you lost the biggest advantage of using a Front-end framework like Ember.JS.

My advice is to try to use **computed property** to change your application's behavior.